# how to preview images , pdf , video files on my web page stored in a folder on my server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have uploaded and downloaded files using PHP, I want to preview different types of files (images, videos, pdf, power point...)
Is there any free API like this http://filepreviews.io? And could I code it by myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard PHP **mime_content_type** function.
Look for its documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

It will NOT read the file itself, but will just return its mime-type based on file extension. I hope that will work for you.